# Location not loading

Tags: ios-appstore, ipod

When I try to change my location for the App Store, it wint load. i go to fetured, my apple id thing, put in my password and everything, but when i click on the country/region button to change it, the page won't load. I have a working Internet connection.

Comment: Is it "Country/Region" you are trying to change?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the location of the Appstore, it is based on the country you have registered it with. Like if you buy a new iPhone in Brazil and you sign in to the Appstore for the first time, it will redirect you to the Appstore of your Apple-id.